# R Shiny Dynamic Report Download

Tags: r, shiny

I have made a dynamic report visually in an r shiny app using renderui. I would like to be able to download this dynamic report but not sure how to correctly create it assuming I am unable to convert a render ui into an html file.

What is the best way to write a dynamic html file that can be displayed in the ui? and then download it?

Below is a minimal reproducible project. The download button is currently just for show.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(DBI)
library(DT)
library(shinycssloaders)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(scales)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  
  dashboardHeader(title = "Key Performance Indicators", titleWidth =300),
  
  dashboardSidebar(width = 300,
                   
                   sidebarMenu(
                     menuItem("User Guide", tabName = "userguide", icon = icon("question-circle")),
                     menuItem("Dashboard", tabName = "dashboard", icon = icon("chart-line"), selected = TRUE)
                   ),
                   
                   selectizeInput(inputId="goals",
                                  label="Goal:",
                                  choices= c("Asset Management"
                                  ),
                                  selected= "Asset Management",
                                  multiple = FALSE),
                   
                   uiOutput("kpis")
                   
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "userguide",
        
        fluidRow(column(width =  12,
                        tabBox(width = NULL,
                               tabPanel("User Guide",
                                        
                                        h3("General"),
                                        h5("")
                               )
                        )
        )
        
        
        )
      ),
      tabItem(
        tabName = "dashboard",
        
        fluidRow(column(width =  12,
                        tabBox(width = NULL,
                               
                               tabPanel("Plot",
                                        plotlyOutput("plot", height = 550) %>%
                                          withSpinner(color="#1b6d96")),
                               
                               tabPanel("Report",
                                        uiOutput("report") %>%
                                          withSpinner(color="#1b6d96")
                               )
                               
                               
                        )
        )
        )
      )
    )
    
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  rawTable <- reactive({
    
    df <- data.frame(KPI =c("Money Spent"),
                     measure = c("Dollars"),
                     FY2015= c(500), 
                     FY2016= c(100),
                     FY2017= c(250),
                     FY2018= c(600), 
                     FY2019= c(750), 
                     FY2020= c(900))
    
    return(df)
  })
  
  output$kpis <- renderUI({
    
    selectizeInput(inputId="kpi",
                   label="KPI:",
                   choices= unique(rawTable()$KPI),
                   selected= unique(rawTable()$KPI[1]),
                   multiple = FALSE)
    
  })
  
  KPIplot <- reactive({
    
    req(input$kpi)
    
    df <- rawTable() %>%
      filter(KPI == input$kpi) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = tidyr::starts_with("FY"),
                          names_to = "Fiscal.Year",
                          values_to = "Value") %>%
      mutate(Values = as.numeric(gsub("[^A-Za-z0-9;._-]","",Value)))
    
    #measure <- toupper(unique(df$`Y Axis Label`))
    
    ggplotly(
      ggplot(
        data = df,
        aes(x = Fiscal.Year, y= Value,
            text = paste0("Fiscal Year: ", gsub("\\.","-",str_remove(Fiscal.Year, "FY")),
                          "<br>Value: ", Value))
      ) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
        scale_y_continuous(labels = comma, breaks = scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)) +
        theme_minimal(),
      tooltip = c("text")
    )
    
  })
  
  output$plot <- renderPlotly({KPIplot()})
  
  output$report <- renderUI({
    
    fluidPage(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          8, align = "right", offset = 2,
          downloadButton("report", "Generate report")
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          8, align="center", offset = 2,
          h1("Key Performance Indicator"),
          hr(),
          h2(input$goals)
        )
      ),
      fluidRow(
        column(
          8, align="left", offset = 2,
          h2(input$kpi),
          br(),
          h3("Description"),
          h5("custom text"),
          br(),
          h3("Performance Data"),
          renderPlotly({KPIplot()}),
          br(),
          h3("Analysis"),
          h5("custom text")
        )
      )
    )
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I have created a shiny UI to select options that are then input into a rmarkdown report and made available as a PDF file for download. You could probably just replicate much of your existing code in the rmarkdown report, so that the PDF report looks very close to the UI you have already created.

Comment: @cory that sounds like it could work. Could you please provide a short reproducible example?

Comment: @Melissa: Here you can find how to: <https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/generating-reports.html>

Comment: @TarJae Thanks! I read this article but didn't seem straight forward for my use case